# get certain row from mysql table comparing with another table value

Tags: mysql

I need some help in mysql query.

I have two tables, like below

table 1

```
ID NAME    ADDRESS
1  test    testing address
2  test1    testing address 
3  test2    testing address
```

table 2

```
ID  user_id    date
1   2          123456789
```

my query was

```
SELECT * FROM table1,table2 on table1.ID = table2.user_id where table2.date != 123456789
```

but it won't work.

I need data from table1 without ID 2 like below output

```
ID name address
1  test1 testing address
3  test3 testing address
```

Comment: your join syntax is wrong, you need to specify the table you are joining from before you use the `on` keyword

Comment: You should try a "join" query. Join syntax is like: SELECT tableX.FieldX, tableY.FieldZ( .. and so on) FROM tableX LEFT JOIN tableY ON(tableX.field = tableY.field) WHERE tableY.date != some_timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Check your syntax

```
 SELECT * FROM table1 t1 
 INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.user_id where t2.date != '123456789'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left join` to get only records that don't exist in the second table

```
SELECT tabl1.* 
FROM table1
left join table2 on table1.ID = table2.user_id 
where table2.user_id is null
```

See [this great explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Hi thanks for your solution. its works well but i need compare with "date" field because if that "date" was not exists then i need that user_id (2) too. like all records from table1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t1.ID <> t2.user_id;
```

Hope it will help you.